# Installing webex on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, webex

I am looking to install webex on my ubuntu 12.04 machine and I find that webex player is available only for windows and mac-os. Can someone please tell me the procedure to install it?

Answer (score 0):

webex player can be start with wine, But the recorder didn't support linux
[download from here](https://webexhelp.webex.com/client/T27LB/ateditor.msi)
then you have have map the wrf file type open with following command :
for example:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/j30wu/.wine" wine "/home/j30wu/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/wbxrecplay/AtAuthor.exe"
-PLAYER
```